# Kubernetes connection refused on port 8080 - Windows 10

Tags: cmd, kubernetes, windows-10, environment-variables

I have following error on Windows10 after installing `kubectl` via 
`choco install kubernetes-cli`:

`PowerShell`

```
PS C:\Users\userA> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

`Cmd`

```
C:\Users\userA>kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I have created `.kube` folder (`C:\Users\userA\.kube`) and inside of it an empty `config` file

I set windows environment variable:

`Variable_name`: `KUBECONFIG`
`value`: `C:\Users\userA\.kube\config`

**EDIT:** I tested it with `running` minikube:

[image]

Comment: Where is your Kubernetes cluster actually running?  That connection data needs to go into the `.kube/config` file.

Comment: I have installed `minikube` also. I do know if it is running. I am running simple command that is `kubectl version` after freshly installing `kubectl` only - as a first command to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out myself - on `Windows 10` 
`Hyper-V` should be turn on if you are using `Docker desktop` but for `minikube` it should be turn off.

When i had turned off `Hyper-V` and restarted my PC - then `minikube start` worked fine.

Comment: Thats basicly not true. If u want to use hyper-v, just create a virtual switch and tell minikube to use hyper-v. See my edited answer

Comment: I tried creating switch, see that in question above i used `mySwitch` in command. I had this switch in `Hyper-v manager`

Answer (score 4):

You need to start the server  first, with:

```
minikube start
```

Edit: As op tries to use hyper-v the following command tells minikube to use hyper-v

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch"
```

To get this workling it is also neccessary to set a virtual switch named "Primary Virtual Switch" in hyper-v.

Comment: I added screenshot where you can see that `minikube` is running but still i got the same output.

Comment: Please try: delete the .kube and .minikube folder, restart your maschine and then start minikube again (it should create the folders automaticly). Are you behind a corporate proxy or acticated firewall?

Comment: After restart I can not delete .minikube folder i have some files and message "The action can't be completed because the file is open in Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management" I needed to delete `VM` from `Hyper-V Manager` to get rid of these files. I think that `minikube start --vm-driver "hyperv" --hyperv-virtual-switch "mySwitch"  --alsologtostderr` command creates only `.minikube` folder not the `.kube` , right?

Comment: I think that from my phone network - the minikube start commands hangs on `Downloading kubelet v1.13.2`. Minikube is `v0.33.1`. See https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2977

Comment: I figured out it myself and added an answer

Comment: To delete the folder you had to stop the kube first. with "minikube stop" and "minikube delete"

Comment: I've deleted the folder many times and i had the same issue with `hyper-v` turned on.